# How do I login to OneDrive (after the initial time) without seeing the permissions screen

Tags: c#, windows, onedrive

I have just started working with the OneDrive API and the sample program that comes with it (OneDriveApiBrowser).

As expected, the first time I logged in (using "Sign In to MSA...", I was asked for credentials, my 2-factor code, and finally a permissions screen asking if I approve of the access that the app wants against my OneDrive account.

But, after I exit the program and restart it, I am not logged in. I repeat going to "Sign In to MSA..." and I am no longer prompted for credentials (as I expected), but I ***am*** prompted with the permissions screen again.

Is there a way of having the app log back in without always prompting the user for permission?

For learning how to use the OneDrive API, I am just using the sample code that Microsoft supplied as part of the API located at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/tree/master/samples/OneDriveApiBrowser. The code can't be downloaded directly from there, but at the root of this project, https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp. This will download the source for the API as well as the sample code and unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more poking around, I finally found out how to do this.  My explanation here will be in the context of the sample program mentioned in the original question above.

In the program, in the `SignIn` method, there was some setup being done which included calling `OneDriveClient.GetMicrosoftAccountClient(...)`, then calling the following:

```
if (!this.oneDriveClient.IsAuthenticated)
{
    await this.oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
}
```

So, two things needed to be done. We need the save the result from the code above, then save the RefreshToken value somewhere safe... (It's just a very long string).

```
if (!this.oneDriveClient.IsAuthenticated)
{
    AccountSession accountSession = await this.oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
    // Save accountSession.RefreshToken somewhere safe...
}
```

Finally, I needed to put an `if` around the `OneDriveClient.GetMicrosoftAccountClient(...)` call and only call it if the saved refresh token has not been saved yet (or as been deleted due to code added to the logout call...) If we **have** a saved refresh token, we call `OneDriveClient.GetSilentlyAuthenticatedMicrosoftAccountClient(...) instead.  The entire SignIn method looks like this when I am done.

```
private async Task SignIn(ClientType clientType)
{
    string refreshToken = null;
    AccountSession accountSession;

    // NOT the best place to save this, but will do for an example...
    refreshToken = Properties.Settings.Default.RefreshToken;

    if (this.oneDriveClient == null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
        {
            this.oneDriveClient = clientType == ClientType.Consumer
                        ? OneDriveClient.GetMicrosoftAccountClient(
                            FormBrowser.MsaClientId,
                            FormBrowser.MsaReturnUrl,
                            FormBrowser.Scopes,
                            webAuthenticationUi: new FormsWebAuthenticationUi())
                        : BusinessClientExtensions.GetActiveDirectoryClient(FormBrowser.AadClientId, FormBrowser.AadReturnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            this.oneDriveClient = await OneDriveClient.GetSilentlyAuthenticatedMicrosoftAccountClient(FormBrowser.MsaClientId,
                    FormBrowser.MsaReturnUrl,
                    FormBrowser.Scopes, 
                    refreshToken);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        if (!this.oneDriveClient.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            accountSession = await this.oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
            // NOT the best place to save this, but will do for an example...
            Properties.Settings.Default.RefreshToken = accountSession.RefreshToken;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        await LoadFolderFromPath();

        UpdateConnectedStateUx(true);
    }
    catch (OneDriveException exception)
    {
        // Swallow authentication cancelled exceptions
        if (!exception.IsMatch(OneDriveErrorCode.AuthenticationCancelled.ToString()))
        {
            if (exception.IsMatch(OneDriveErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Authentication failed",
                    "Authentication failed",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                var httpProvider = this.oneDriveClient.HttpProvider as HttpProvider;
                httpProvider.Dispose();
                this.oneDriveClient = null;
            }
            else
            {
                PresentOneDriveException(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, I updated the logout code

```
private async void signOutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.oneDriveClient != null)
    {
        await this.oneDriveClient.SignOutAsync();
        ((OneDriveClient)this.oneDriveClient).Dispose();
        this.oneDriveClient = null;

        // NOT the best place to save this, but will do for an example...
        Properties.Settings.Default.RefreshToken = null;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    UpdateConnectedStateUx(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wl.offline_access` scope is required by applications to save the user consent information and refresh the access token without a UI prompt.

For more details on the scopes that you can use in your application see https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#authentication-scopes

Comment: OK, but that scope is already there... `private static readonly string[] Scopes = { "onedrive.readwrite", "wl.offline_access", "wl.signin" };`. Also, I am using the C# SDK and not the https interface directly, so I am unsure of how to translate that documentation to the c# API framwork.

Comment: Could you provide the details/code for how you are creating the setting up the OneDrive client and the configuration the Authenticate call?

Comment: Sure, I am just using the sample code for the API. I edited my OP with details of where it can be found.  At this point, it is just "stock code" with no changes...