# C# OneDrive Stop Constantly Asking For Permissions

Tags: c#, onedrive

Using C# to login to OneDrive using their official NuGET provided SDK.

This logs in and asks for permissions and displays the root folder contents just fine, but every time I launch the program it asks for permissions. How can I get it to stop?

I don't see anything in their samples different from what I'm doing. But, it's possible I over looked something.

```
private IOneDriveClient oneDriveClient { get; set; }
private static readonly string[] oneDriveScopes = 
{
    "wl.signin", 
    "wl.offline_access", 
    "onedrive.readwrite"
};

private async Task oneDriveLogin()
{
    if (oneDriveClient == null)
    {
        oneDriveClient = OneDriveClient.GetMicrosoftAccountClient(
            "APP_CID_HERE", 
            @"https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf", 
            oneDriveScopes, 
            webAuthenticationUi: new FormsWebAuthenticationUi());

        try
        {
            if (!oneDriveClient.IsAuthenticated)
                await oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
        }
        catch (OneDriveException exception)
        {
            //proper error catching here
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Screenshot if anyone needs it:

[image]

**UPDATE2:** Found the answer - [How do I login to OneDrive (after the initial time) without seeing the permissions screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775920/how-do-i-login-to-onedrive-after-the-initial-time-without-seeing-the-permissio)

Comment: `new FormsWebAuthenticationUi()` is displaying the login dialog to the user, and if you're not storing the username or password anywhere how else would you expect to authenticate?

Comment: It authenticates just fine, it's the permissions that constantly pops up.